# Find the minimize value of $P=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, mixing-variables

> For non-negative numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$  such that $ab+bc+ca=1$  find the minimize value of $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+a^2}}$$

---

By C-S: $\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\right)\cdot P\ge\left(1+1+1\right)^2$

And $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{2}}=\dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\Rightarrow\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\ge\dfrac{2\left(a+b+c\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\ge\dfrac{2\cdot\sqrt{3\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\Rightarrow P\ge\dfrac{\left(1+1+1\right)^2}{\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}}=\dfrac{3\sqrt{6}}{2}$

When $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

If $a=0;b=c=1$ it's seem wrong

Comment: from where do you know that a global Minimum exists?

Comment: I don't follow your claim: "By C-S: $\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\right)\cdot P\ge\left(1+1+1\right)^2$"

Comment: Your logic is wrong, you can not get $$P\ge\dfrac{\left(1+1+1\right)^2}{\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}}=\dfrac{3\sqrt{6}}{2}$$ since $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\ge\dfrac{2\left(a+b+c\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\ge\dfrac{2\cdot\sqrt{3\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$Please note that in the second inequality, it is $\geqslant$ not $\leqslant$. If it is $\leqslant$, then you are correct.

Comment: or do you mean $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+c}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+a}}\geq 2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$? with the same conditions

Comment: Dear Michael, have you proved the inequality above?

Comment: i also but tomorrow i must go to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=b=1$ and $c=0$ then we get a value $2+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2}}\geq2+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$

Indeed, let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$.

Hence, $$\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{(a+c)(b+c)}{(a+c)^2+(b+c)^2}=\frac{c(a+b+2c)(2ab+ac+bc)}{a^2+b^2)((a+c)^2+(b+c)^2}\geq0,$$
$$\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+c^2}-\frac{b+c}{a+c}=\frac{c(2ab+ac-c^2)}{(a+c)(a^2+c^2)}\geq0$$ and
$$\frac{ab+ac+bc}{b^2+c^2}-\frac{a+c}{b+c}=\frac{c(2ab+bc-c^2)}{(b+c)(b^2+c^2)}\geq0.$$
Now, let $\frac{a+c}{b+c}=x^2$ and $\frac{b+c}{a+c}=y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are positives.

Hence, $xy=1$ and we need to prove that
$$x+y+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\geq2+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or
$$x+y-2\sqrt{xy}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ or
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\geq\frac{(x-y)^2}{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt2)}$$ or
$$\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt2)\geq(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2.$$
Now, by C-S twice we obtain:
$$\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{(1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2)}\geq x+y=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(1^2+1^2)((\sqrt{x})^2+(\sqrt{y})^2)\geq\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt2\geq2,$$
which is true by AM-GM:
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt2\geq\sqrt{2xy}+\sqrt2=2\sqrt2>2.$$
Done!

Comment: From $\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2\ge \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)}\Leftrightarrow 1\ge \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2\ge \left(x-y\right)^2\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2$

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(x-y\right)^2\ge \left(x-y\right)^2\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2\right)}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)\ge \left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)^2$ ? Seem wrong because $a=b=1$ shoud $(x-y)^2=0$

Comment: @Word Shallow I divided both sides by $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$.

Comment: @Word Shallow $(x-y)^2=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2$. See better please.

Comment: If $a=b=1;c=0$ have $\frac{a+c}{b+c}=x^2\Rightarrow \frac{1+0}{1+0}=x^2\Rightarrow x^2=1\Rightarrow x=1\frac{b+c}{a+c}=y^2\Rightarrow y=1$ should $\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2=0$ can't divide $\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)^2$

Comment: @Word Shallow. If $x=y$ then the inequality is obvious. If $x\neq y$ we can divide by $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63484/discussion-between-word-shallow-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 0):

**Proof.**

We'll prove $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}. \tag{*}$$
WLOG, assuming that $c=\min\{a,b,c\}.$ We split the inequality into two cases.

- $c=0: ab=1$ the $(*)$ becomes$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$or $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+\dfrac{1}{a^2}}}+a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$ or $\left(t=a+\dfrac{1}{a}\right)$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}+t\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\iff (t-2)\left(1-\frac{t+2}{\sqrt{2(t^2-2)}(\sqrt{t^2-2}+\sqrt{2})}\right)\ge 0.\tag{**}$$
  The last inequality is true since $t\ge 2: 2\sqrt{t^2-2}\ge 2\sqrt{2}>2;\sqrt{2}t^2-t-2\sqrt{2}>0. $
- $c>0:$ it implies $a,b>0.$ Notice that $$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{c^2+a^2}> \frac{b}{a} \iff \frac{c(b^2+ab-ac)}{c^2+a^2}> 0,$$ $$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{c^2+b^2}> \frac{a}{b} \iff \frac{c(a^2+ab-bc)}{c^2+a^2}> 0,$$and$$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{b^2+a^2}>\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}. $$
  Hence, it remains to prove  $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}}\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$Set $t=\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a}}\ge 2$ and the inequality turns out $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}+t\ge 2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$which is proven in $(**)$ already.

We end proof here. Equality holds at $a=b=1;c=0$ and permutations.

Comment: Oh, now I see my main idea is quite similar to Michael Rozenberg 's answer.